# WSO2ESB 4.8.0 and WSO2IS 5.0.0 secure REST endpoint with OAuth2

Tags: java, security, rest, wso2

I have followed [this tutorial](http://malalanayake.wordpress.com/2013/04/05/apply-oauth2-0-base-security-for-rest-endpoint-with-wso2esb-4-6-0-and-wso2is-4-1-1-alpha/) to implement an API in WSO2 ESB 4.8.0.
The following steps are depicted in the tutorial:

1. Create the custom handler to validate the Bearer token.
2. Create API element in the ESB and pointing the rest endpoint that you have
3. Include created handler to the created API element.
4. Go to IS and create the OAuth2.0 application and get the Access token form IS
5. Invoke the API with the valid access token.

I can invoke the API in step 5 with any token, or an empty token. The API configured in the ESB should only return with the correct access token that is provided in step 4.

Is it missing something to validate the token properly in the handler or in the API configuration?

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved!
The handler was not properly deployed on the esb server